# concatenating strings and snprintf in c

Tags: c, concatenation, printf

I'm wondering if this is the proper way to `concatenate` and `NUL` terminate strings including width.

```
#define FOO "foo"
const char *bar = "bar";
int n = 10;
float f = 10.2;

char *s;
int l;

l = snprintf (NULL, 0, "%-6s %-10s %4d %4f",FOO, bar, n, f);
s = malloc (l + 4); // should it be the number of formats tags?
if (s == null) return 1;
sprintf (s, "%-6s %-10s %4d %4f", FOO, bar, n, f);
```

Comment: It might be a good idea for maintenance purposes to define one format string that is used by both the `snprintf` and the `sprintf`. It'd really suck if it got changed in one place and not the other!

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, would it be possible to post a sample code in reference to this? Thanks

Comment: Just declare something like `const char* fmt_str = "%-6s %-10s %4d %4f";` and use that as your format string in both places.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few systems have a function `asprintf` in their standard C libraries that does exactly what you do here: allocate and `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add `1` to the value returned by `snprintf()`, since there is only one null terminator added.

However, you do need to check for `l == -1` (indicating that `snprintf()` failed).

Comment: `snprintf` isn't defined in the original C89, and I think that there were a few platforms with non-C99-compliant implementations, but C99 does say that `snprintf(NULL, ...)` is supposed to work the way OP uses it here.

Comment: @ephemient: Quite so, I've removed that bit.